# Raster style based on percentile QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, style

Is there a way to get similar raster styling in QGIS as ArcGIS does with classified raster data based on percentile scores? In other words, I want an equal number of pixels in one color for my entire raster. I already tried all settings for pseudocolor in QGIS. QGIS 2.12.1 Windows

In ArcGIS this functionality can be found in Layer properties - Symbology - Classified - Classify - Quantile

This is easy with shapefiles but not evident to me with raster files

UPDATE: I started working on a plugin but ran into problems: [Quantile in QGIS python Plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186343/quantile-in-qgis-python-plugin)

[image]

Dialog window in arcGIS

[image: Equal Interval histogram]

Classes in Histogram for equal interval setting

[image: Quantile Histogram]

classes in histogram for quantile (Equal number of pixels in class) setting

Answer (score 3):

The singleband pseudocolor dialogue has an 'equal interval' option on which you can set the # of classes and the colours themselves:

[image]

Is that what you're after?

Comment: thanks for your comment. I want to set the intervals such that the amount of pixels in each bin is the same. I believe this is a percentile or quantile approach. I cuurently calculate the quantile (5 classes) scores using python and copy them into Qgis but this should be easier.

Comment: I can't see what you're describing in ArcMap... are you able to post a screen shot of what you're after? When I use the same settings dialogue box you're describing, it's doing the same thing the QGIS dialogue is doing above...

Comment: Ah so it seems QGIS lacks a 'quantile' method... that would be what you're after then?

Comment: exactly, plugin or workaround is OK as well

Comment: Seems like PostGIS Raster might have a solution, at least for figuring out the breaks: http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Quantile.html given the result, you could set your symbols manually... but yeah, maybe a feature request for QGIS to have a few more raster symbology methods?

Comment: There's also a GRASS solution: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.quantile.html to at least compute the breaks...

Comment: @RutgerH I tried the GRASS r.quantile on my raster (without a GRASS mapset you can run GRASS tools on local data with QGIS W/ GRASS) but I can't figure out how to interpret the output... more to come...

Comment: Amyone already working on a plugin for this?

Comment: I haven't seen anything, but I would suggest a feature request for QGIS... seems like a logical addition to the symbol categories...

Comment: @RutgerH I think I figured out how to apply this output but I need to find a raster with a better range of values to apply it to...